# Array-flattened nested resources in rest api?

Tags: api, rest

I need to provide REST API for complex nested resources.

I do not really like inline embedding, because it forces data duplicates in response, which makes responses bigger and harder to interpret by the frontend (e.g. several cars can have single engine, but i will need to duplicate it in the response).

```
GET /cars
{
  "cars": {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Batmobile",
    "spoiler": 192, // nested
    "engine": 18 // nested
  },
  "engines": {
    "id": 18,
    "turbine": 671 // nested
    ...
  },
  "spoilers": {
    "id": 192,
    ...
  },
  "turbines": {
    "id": 671,
    ...
  }
}
```

I would like to use following format, because:

- data is normalized
- data is easily integrated with angular2 data stores

Hovewer, i was not able to find any standards or any REST API providers implementing such format. All standards usually use inline embedding.

Are there any cons not to implement such a protocol?

Comment: Is the sample json you provide what you want to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

From my understanding of your post, you want to flatten what otherwise it would naturally be a document with nested documents.

I can't see how flattening can enhance readability. Further more, it's unorthodox and will hinder API understanding.

In your sample, you are requesting `GET /cars` but you are retrieving cars and all related resources as first level items. How will you access and update individual resources?.

Nesting and/or breaking resources into different endpoints is necessary for several reasons:

1. The client usually does not need all cars and all its parts in one request. It will usually navigate resources, starting with cars, then a car detail, then its parts.
2. Separate resources on separate URIs each with specific semantics helps aligning these with CRUD operations on the resource. This will be really difficult with your flattened representation.
3. Different resources on separate URIs each with its independent representation will help you manage your API and contain change and reduce coupling
4. If you are trying to build a REST API, the flattened representation you suggest will end up messing things around.

I'd suggest:

1. That you render related resources as links (line in [HAL](http://stateless.co/hal_specification.html)):

   `GET /cars
   [
   {
   "name": "Batmobile",
   "links": [
      { "rel" : "self",
        "href": "https://api.superauto.com/cars/1"
      },
      { "rel" : "spoiler",
        "href" : "https://api.superauto.com/spoilers/192"
      },
      { "rel": "engine", 
        "href": "https://api.superauto.com/engines/18"
      }
    ]
   }
   ]`
2. That you keep each resource separate in different URIs
3. That you stick to a RESTful API design. Check [REST API Tutorial](http://www.restapitutorial.com/) and [Restful best practices](http://www.restapitutorial.com/media/RESTful_Best_Practices-v1_1.pdf)

There are libraries (at least in the JVM ecosystem: Java, Groovy, Scala, Kotlin) that support HAL. If this representation does not fit all your needs you can also use libraries that support embedding resources on a per request basis, so you can override the default response embedding related resources.

Answer (score -1):

[normalizr](https://github.com/paularmstrong/normalizr) could help integrating it more easily to your  angular2 data stores.